# Atributo translate: como será o uso desse futuro atributo?

Tags: html, html5

A que passos anda o experimento desse atributo e quando os navegadores vão começar a aceitar seu uso? E alguém consegue entender e arrisca explicar qual será sua real utilidade nos elementos da HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ninguém pode responder adequadamente a primeira parte. A segunda, no seu cerne, também não servirá para nada. Futurologia não é o objetivo aqui.

O atributo [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/translate) serve para dar semântica ao conteúdo e ferramentas serão criadas ou melhor adaptadas para aproveitar esta informação adicional. Em tese as ferramentas de tradução de conteúdo on-line ou alguma interna do desenvolvedor poderão tomar decisões de como proceder com aquele conteúdo. Ela provavelmente terá pouca relevância e uso, muito esforço para um público bem seleto, depende da necessidade.

Exemplo de uso:

```
<p>I bring an apple and my <span translate="no">Apple</span> to school.</p>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Translate.html).

O nome da empresa não será traduzido.

Comment: Uma grande dúvida é: depois que o atributo começar a ser aceito pelos navegadores, sempre que quiser permitir-se a tradução dos elementos terei que informar translate="yes" para cada um? Usualmente não seria melhor se todos os elementos aceitassem por padrão a tradução e nos elementos que não devem permitir tradução utilizar um atributo boolean de nome "notranslate"? Mas, como você já disse: futurologia não é o nosso objetivo. Obrigada pela resposta ;)

Comment: Pelo que entendi da proposta não precisa, é mais para marcar o que não deve traduzir. Mas também entendo que cada ferramenta poderá adotar um postura diferente, só acho que fugirá do padrão não fazer desta forma.